# Implementing dropdown list in Form builder, angular 5

Tags: angular, forms

I wanted to implement a dropdown list, instead of typing value, so I've created a class

```
export class Roles {
id: number;
name: string;
}
```

And imported it in my app.component.ts

```
 roles: Roles[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Org manager' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Supervisor' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Member' }
 ];
```

And in my app.component.html

```
         <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('Email')">
                <label for="Email" class="control-label 
         required">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="Email" class="form-control" 
       formControlName="Email">
          </div>

     <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('RoleId')">
                <label for="RoleId" class="control-label" 
     formControlName="RoleId">Role</label>
                <select id="RoleId"  formControlName="RoleId"  class="form-
     control">
                    <option *ngFor="let r of roles" [value]="r.id">
                        {{r.name}}
                    </option>
               </select>
            </div>
```

Noted that I had a function form, where the roles were typed, but that's not solution, so I'm trying to figure out how to implement Role.Id in my form builder, I'm using angular reactive forms...

```
    ngOnInit() { 

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        Email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        RoleId: [null, Validators.required],


    });

}
```

Am I on the right course, what should I do to get my RoleId in my formBuilder get the value of selected option in the dropdown list?

Is there a way I can implemented it since I send an object like this, to my form to submit?

I have a class

```
export class employee {

Id: string; 
Email: string;
RoleId: string;

}
```

And in app.component.ts 
        Demoemployee: employee;

```
    GetDemoObject(myForm: NgForm): employee { this.Demoemployee = new 
    employee; this.Demoemployee.Email = myForm.value.Email; 
    this.Demoemployee= myForm.value.RoleId; return this.Demoemployee; }
```

Comment: You have already it. to check it write {{form?.value |json}} in your html

Comment: It doesn't work, I get an err in console saying No value accessor for form control with name: 'RoleId', on my component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. This will work. :)

```
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('Email')">
            <label for="Email" class="control-label 
     required">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="Email" class="form-control" 
   formControlName="Email">
      </div>

 <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('RoleId')">
            <label for="RoleId" class="control-label">Role</label>
        <select [formControl]="form.controls['RoleId']">
       <option *ngFor="let r of roles" [value]="r.id">
                    {{r.name}}
                </option>
    </select>
        </div>
```

in Component.ts

```
GetDemoObject(myForm: NgForm): employee { this.Demoemployee = new 
    employee; this.Demoemployee.Email = myForm.value.Email; 
    this.Demoemployee.RoleId= myForm.value.RoleId; return this.Demoemployee; }
```

Comment: that helps, sends the correct form values, I've edited question at the end, so if you can help me with that also, thanks a lot

Comment: I've updated the answer. Have a look at it now.
you can get the Role id from this.Demoemployee.RoleId